# Merge text files next to each other

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have `.txt` data from spectrometer with 800 lines and 5 columns. And I want to merge about 15 these files next to each other. So final `.txt` file should have 800 lines and  75 columns.

All `.txt` files looks like this:

```
Wave   ;Sample   ;Dark     ;Reference;Absorbance
[nm]   ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[A.U]
200.00;   34.647;   -0.317;   79.668; 0.35734
201.00;   29.937;  -21.220;   70.385; 0.25357
202.00;   48.826;   -0.527;   99.657; 0.30721
203.00;   43.201;    4.165;  136.775; 0.53103
...
```

Desired file:

```
Wave   ;Sample   ;Dark     ;Reference;Absorbance; Wave   ;Sample   ;Dark     ;Reference;Absorbance
[nm]   ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[A.U];  [nm]   ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[A.U]
200.00;   34.647;   -0.317;   79.668; 0.35734;    200.00;   34.647;   -0.317;   79.668; 0.35734;
201.00;   29.937;  -21.220;   70.385; 0.25357;    201.00;   29.937;  -21.220;   70.385; 0.25357
202.00;   48.826;   -0.527;   99.657; 0.30721;    202.00;   48.826;   -0.527;   99.657; 0.30721
203.00;   43.201;    4.165;  136.775; 0.53103;    203.00;   43.201;    4.165;  136.775; 0.53103
```

I tried:

```
cat *.txt > file.txt
```

But this add `.txt` files like new lines not like new columns.

Comment: Add some example input files and your desired output from those.

Comment: If you want to do it only once, you can do manually/visually in Libre Office Calc, by pasting the files into the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re looking for the `paste` utility, e.g.

```
paste *.txt > file.txt
```

Check its manual page for details, most notably the `-d` option to specify the delimiter.

Comment: I'm probably looking for sdiff. But I don't know what option use. Each file should be delimited with ";" but there is "tab |".

Comment: @AdamSrut, Please explain with much more details, what you want! Edit your original question to add these details.

Comment: sorry sdiff works only on two files... I edited my question.

Answer (score 4):

### Simple example

I set the separator to 'space' and eliminate multiple spaces.

```
$ cat file-1
ett tu tre
1    2   3
11   22 33
$ cat file-2
fyra fem sex
4     5   6
44   55  66

$ cat file-3
sju atta nio
7      8   9
77    88  99

$ paste file-?
ett tu tre  fyra fem sex    sju atta nio
1    2   3  4     5   6 7      8   9
11   22 33  44   55  66 77    88  99

$ paste -d ' ' file-?
ett tu tre fyra fem sex sju atta nio
1    2   3 4     5   6 7      8   9
11   22 33 44   55  66 77    88  99

$ paste -d ' ' file-? | tr -s ' ' ' '
ett tu tre fyra fem sex sju atta nio
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99
```

### Suggested command line

Maybe you want to eliminate the spaces? You want to keep semicolon as separator. Try with the following command line

```
paste -d ';' input-filespec-with-wildcard | sed 's/ //g' > output-file
```

where `input-filespec-with-wildcard` could be `*.txt` (if the files to be merged are the only `txt` files in the directory).

### Edit (using the real data)

- Convert the files to unix/linux text format, `CarriageReturn + LineFeed` --> `LineFeed` with `dos2unix`
- Remove blank lines with the following command

  ```
  for i in *.TXT;do echo sed '/^$/'d "$i" > "${i/.TXT/.txt}";done
  ```
- Remove header lines with the following command

  ```
  for i in *.txt;do grep ';*;' "$i" > "${i/.txt/.txt1}";done
  ```

  (Header lines do not contain at least two semicolons.)
- Merge the files with the following command

  ```
  paste -d ';' *.txt1 | sed 's/ //g' > merged-file.txt
  ```

I read the merged file into LibreOffice Calc and used semicolon as separator. It looks like I think you want to have it. I hope it works for you according to these instructions. Otherwise please describe your remaining problem and tell me if you want me to upload 'my' `merged-file.txt`.

### LibreOffice Calc

If you want to do it only once, you can do manually/visually in Libre Office Calc, by pasting the files into the spreadsheet. You can edit the positions in the spreadsheet and remove the lines, that create confusion.

I would say that it is rather easy to do it manually in LibreOffice Calc, but if this is something that you will do many times or with a great number of files, it is better to use and maybe refine the command line method.

Comment: That is almost it! But I get line from each file under line from previous file as a result. So I tried to eliminate end of lines "\n" and I type    | sed 's/\n//g'    but that does not work.

Comment: You can try `tr '\n' ';'` to convert the unwanted newlines to semicolons (which you use as separators). But it will remove all newlines, and that is probably not what you want. If you have blank lines (two newlines next to each other), you can try `sed '/^$/'d` where ^ marks the beginning of a line and $ marks the end of a line and d tells sed to delete the line (the blank line).

Comment: But I am guessing. You can make it easier to help, if you **upload some of the real files**, that you want to merge and post a link to them. Then I can develop a method, that works for the real case. (If the files are secret, I can give you my public key for gpg encryption so that you can make them readable only for me.)

Comment: Yes I understand. Here is link to the files <https://vscht-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/sruta_vscht_cz/Eqqp0lU1LKRGhXxrRLMZKwYBTa1pktZtMv263CF9seevTQ?e=AWaQer>

Comment: @AdamSrut, Have a look at what I think is a working solution.